# EventLoopGroup and BIO operation.

Tags: netty

I'm having Netty Web server which should retrieve data using Hibernate and return response to the client.

So I just wonder if my implementation is correct

```
   ChannelPipeline pipeline = ch.pipeline();
        EventExecutorGroup ex = new DefaultEventExecutorGroup(64);

        pipeline.addLast("decoder", new HttpRequestDecoder());
        pipeline.addLast("aggregator", new HttpObjectAggregator(65536));
        pipeline.addLast("encoder", new HttpResponseEncoder());
        pipeline.addLast("chunkedWriter", new ChunkedWriteHandler());

        pipeline.addLast(ex,"handler", new HttpWebServerHandler());
```

and then inside of `messageReceived` method:

```
    @Override
    public void messageReceived(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, FullHttpRequest request)
            throws Exception {
         if (!request.getDecoderResult().isSuccess()) {
                sendError(ctx, BAD_REQUEST);
                return;
            }
          ctx.executor().execute(new MyRunnable(ctx)); 
    }
```

and inside Runnable:

```
@Override
public void run() {

        SomeObejct so = HibernateTemplate.getSomeObject() ;
                    String serializedSo = serialize(so);
          FullHttpResponse res = new DefaultFullHttpResponse(
                    HTTP_1_1, OK, Unpooled.copiedBuffer(serializedSo, CharsetUtil.UTF_8));
            res.headers().set(CONTENT_TYPE, "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");                      ctx.write(res).addListener(ChannelFutureListener.CLOSE);     
}
```

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this looks correct. What you may want to think about is to remove the HttpObjectAggregator from the ChannelPipeline and so save some memory overhead. But be aware that you need to handle the different HTTP messages parts by your own then.